# mongodb script file

Tags: database, mongodb, shell, command-line, mongodb-java

I am newbie to mongodb.

We can execute list of queries by specifying it in a script `.sql` file in relational db and can run it by running the command source `c:\test.sql`.

For instance

```sql
CREATE DATABASE `sandbox`;
USE `sandbox`;

CREATE TABLE pet (
    name VARCHAR(20), 
    owner VARCHAR(20),
    species VARCHAR(20), 
    sex CHAR(1), 
    birth DATE, 
   death DATE
);
SHOW TABLES;
```

Then it can be execute as

```
$ mysql -u root -p admin
mysql > source test.sql;
```

#### Questions

- How can we do that in mongodb?
- Which type of file can we store `mongodb` commands?
- How can we execute a `mongodb` script?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do it with shell script. You can execute the commands using the following command.

```
./mongo server:27017/dbname --quiet my_commands.js
```

For details check [Scripting the shell](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Scripting+the+shell) document in Mongo docs.

Comment: Correct link is https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the answer is just too old, or there are different ways to do it.
Well theoretically the answer specifies a '.js' file but tells about "can do it with shell script".

Anyways, I guess could be that now there is better documentation, but here another way to do it

##### How to store those commands in mongodb script?

I think the question is also really "Which file type/extension should be use to create mongo script files"

Using **Javascript** (no need any type of library just mongosh)

Example

```js
db = connect( 'mongodb://localhost/sandbox' );
console.log(db);
console.log(Object.keys(db));
```

##### How can we do that in mongodb?

From the `mongosh` shell use the `load` command with an absolute or relative path to the script.

##### Example

Assuming we are using linux do the following

```bash
mkdir mongo_sandbox
cd mongo_sandbox
touch mongo_script.js
```

Now let's create a mongo Javascript script, you know use vim, VSCode, pen and paper.. whatever

```js
db = connect( 'mongodb://localhost/myDatabase' );
db.movies.insertMany( [
   {
      title: 'Titanic',
      year: 1997,
      genres: [ 'Drama', 'Romance' ]
   },
   {
      title: 'Spirited Away',
      year: 2001,
      genres: [ 'Animation', 'Adventure', 'Family' ]
   },
   {
      title: 'Casablanca',
      genres: [ 'Drama', 'Romance', 'War' ]
   }
] )

let movies = db.movies.find();

console.log(movies);
```

Cool now, lunch `mongosh`

```bash
mongosh sandbox
# ...bla bla bla 
sandbox>
```

Run the script

```bash
load( "./mongo_script.js" )
```

Which outputs

```bash
sandbox> load( "./mongo_script.js" )
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("64e8560e2932f758ce7d11a3"),
    title: 'Titanic',
    year: 1997,
    genres: [ 'Drama', 'Romance' ]
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("64e8560e2932f758ce7d11a4"),
    title: 'Spirited Away',
    year: 2001,
    genres: [ 'Animation', 'Adventure', 'Family' ]
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("64e8560e2932f758ce7d11a5"),
    title: 'Casablanca',
    genres: [ 'Drama', 'Romance', 'War' ]
  }
]
true
```

#### Documentation

- [Write Scripts](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/write-scripts/)